# React Flow ignores `type Props`

Tags: reactjs

`"babel-plugin-react-flow-props-to-prop-types": "^0.15.0"` installed.
`.babelrc` has `"plugins": [
    ["react-flow-props-to-prop-types"]`
Application itself runs perfectly well with code:

```
import * as React from "react";
type Props = {
  variant: string,
  getData: func
};

export class CityInputContainer extends React.Component<Props> {
     submitName = e => {
    //----------------------------
    this.props.getData(this.props.variant, this.state.city);
    //----------------------------
  };
}
```

But there is no any props type strict policy. I mean, this `variant: number` works 
 without any warning.
And this `React.Component<BlaBla> {}` works as well.
Everything is going as I've just commented out `CityInputContainer.propTypes = {
     variant: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
     getData: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}`
What's wrong with Flow? Shouldn't I expect an error message?

Comment: What is the full Flow output? Also, what Flow version are you using?

Comment: Flow itself works, its version is `"flow-bin": "^0.63.1"` File itself has `// @flow` but wrong props type does not alert.